# Flowgear: The 'Start' Node was not found in the correct sequence

Tags: integration, flowgear

While doing my certification in Flowgear I am getting this error while submitting the exercise number 11.
During production run there is no error.

Error - The 'Start' Node was not found in the correct sequence.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually because the Start Node name has been changed. Click the Start Node header, delete the name, press return to commit the changes and try again.